# Sending email via GMAIL using Powershell in VSTS

Tags: powershell, email, gmail, azure-devops, release-management

I want to send an email at the end of a VSTS release with some additional data. I am using a powershell release task and am using the Gmail SMTP server. The powershell script is as follows:

```
$b = Invoke-WebRequest "http://mywebsite" -usebasicparsing
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject =  "Swagger"
$message.body = $b
$message.to.add("me@hotmail.com")
$message.from = "source@gmail.com"
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587");
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, "apppassword");
$smtp.send($message)
```

Since I am using 2 factor authentication, I am using an app password in the code above. This works fine when I run it from my local machine. However, as part of the release process, it gives me the following error:

> "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not 
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required"

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Where is $Username defined ?

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver ! I had $UserName defined earlier but since VSTS powershell tasks only allow for 250 characters for the inline script, I removed it. Thank you !

Comment: not a problem mate. Enjoy Coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this:

```
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$Username = "username@gmail.com"
$Password = "password"
$to = "username_to_send@gmail.com"
#$cc = "username@gmail.com"
$subject = "Email Subject"
$body = "Insert body text here"
#$attachment = "C:\attachedFile.txt"
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
#$message.cc.add($cc)
$message.from = $username
#$message.attachments.add($attachment)
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.send($message)
write-host "Mail Sent successfully using GMAIL"
```